# Adding days to current date in java

Tags: java, sql, hadoop, hive

I just want to add the 3 days to the current date and print the new date in hive query using java..
please help me out

Comment: please show your current code

Comment: i want to use this in hive query....

Comment: 'I want to use' not a way to ask your problem, show us what you have tried so far.@satish

Answer (score 2):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date());
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 3);
```